# Parse iOS - delete method returns true but record is not deleted

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to delete a record from Parse with the method deleteInBackgroundWithBlock. I'm getting `true` on the `succeeded` parameter in the block. However, the record still there on the parse panel.

Here is my code:

```
let follow = ["objectId": "XXXXXXX"]

let rawFollow: PFObject = PFObject(
        className: "Follow",
        dictionary: follow)

rawFollow.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    // succeeded = true, but record was not deleted....
}
```

Comment: what happens when you try it synchronously (i.e. `- (BOOL)delete:(NSError **)error`)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `objectWithClassName:dictionary:`, you should be using `objectWithoutDataWithClassName:objectId:`. Most likely what you're doing is creating a new object with a custom column of data and then deleting it before it's ever saved / uploaded. Using the other method is the appropriate way to create a placeholder for a known object id without having to query for the object.

Comment: Thank you!, you saved me from a lot of hair pulling